# What are Cabinet and HV formats?

Tags: prints, paper-size

Computer print dialogs, including the one used by MS Word on Windows 10, include some random predefined [paper sizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size), *apparently* intended for [photographic prints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photo_print_sizes). Not all of them are part of the [PWG 5101-1](http://ftp.pwg.org/pub/pwg/candidates/cs-pwgmsn20-20130328-5101.1.pdf) set collected by printer manufacturers, maintained by IANA as part of [IPP](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipp-registrations/):
I do not know nor can explain **Cabinet** (10 to 12 cm by 16.5 cm) and **HV** (c. 10 cm by 18 cm) at least.

- Are these indeed standard photographic sizes used for digital prints?
  ([Cabinet cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabinet_card) have apparently been dead for a century, so no need for print-outs.)
- Where do the terms come from, the acronym *HV* in particular?
- What is the exact definition? Does it use inches or (milli-/centi-)meters?

Comment: Random?  The programmers put a bunch paper sizes on the wall, closed there eyes and threw darts at them, ending up with a random set  of sizes??  Perhaps you meant to say miscellaneous ?

Comment: I meant there are several ones on there that are not relevant for the application at hand, others are repeated under different names or approximations or orientations, while some important ones are missing. Predefined print sizes are a mess in many cases. Anyway, that is not the primary focus here.

Answer (score 3):

**Supported paper sizes are made available by the printer driver.** You likely have a printer driver installed that supports photo papers. The HP website lists supported papers for the [HP Deskjet D2600 Series](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01664447). Among others, it lists:

```
Plain paper
   Cabinet                      127 x 177.8 mm (5 x 7 inches)

Photo paper
   Cabinet                      120 x 165 mm (4.72 x 6.5 inches)
   Borderless Cabinet           120 x 165 mm (4.72 x 6.5 inches)
   Borderless HV Photo paper    101 x 180 mm (4.0 x 7.1 inches)
```

I am unable to find photo papers in theses sizes available for sale, so it seems to be just a way to maximize specs to make a product seem better than it is. The closest sizes I see for sale are 5x7 and 4x6.